# why is the below code has time complexity of o(logn)

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, time-complexity

I have tried to understand the time complexity of the below code. When I try to calculate the timecomplexity myself it is coming out to be o(n). Because the "NO_OF_BITS" is always same for any int and therefore the loop doesn't increase/decrease with the input. I was not sure about the bitwise operations that are executed inside the loop. Can anyone help me understand/calculate the time complexity of this code.

```
    unsigned int reverseBits(unsigned int num)
    {
       int  NO_OF_BITS = sizeof(num) * 8;
       int reverse_num = 0;
       int i;
       for (i = 0; i < NO_OF_BITS; i++)
     {
       if((num & (1 << i)))
         reverse_num |= 1 << ((NO_OF_BITS - 1) - i);  
     }
       return reverse_num;
    }
```

Comment: Well, yes `(num & (1 << i))` is executed N times. All bits are looked at. Who said this is O(log N)?

Comment: @cricket_007: `N` as in `num`, not `NO_OF_BITS`.

Comment: Why do you think this is `O(logN)` ?

Comment: @Eric I guess it wasn't stated what N was

Comment: @cricket_007: IMHO, it would make sense to use `num` because of  `reverseBits(num)`.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen - I didn't say it is logN. But the article I came across in the process to find if there is any code with better time complexity than o(n) posted it as o(logn).

Comment: As both answers and comments here state, the premise is wrong, now I know you've read an article that states this is `O(LogN)`, can you please state which article?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen - http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-an-efficient-c-program-to-reverse-bits-of-a-number/

Comment: Well that article is wrong. If the loop is going to run through `NO_OF_BITS` every time then time complexity is O(1).

Comment: The only world where you could make this *somewhat* related to "N" is where you have a compiler and a programming language where `int num` isn't going to be a fixed type, but more of a "integer with an unknown and possibly large size" type. In every programming language, framework and platform when "unsigned int" is going to have a fixed meaning, this is going to be `O(1)`.

Comment: I don't think that we should make the mistake here of considering a time complexity for an *implementation* (which is limited by irrelevant platform constraints), we should rather consider the *algorithm*.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: Python, Ruby and many more languages...

Comment: I forgot to add ... and that still allows the syntax of the code in the question.

Answer (score 5):

With your logic, the code is actually `O(1)` because `NO_OF_BITS` will always be `32`.

If you talk about time complexity and asymptotic behaviour, you have to increase the input size though. This code is `O(NO_OF_BITS)`, which is `O(log(num))`.

Since the input of the function is `num`, it makes sense to define `n` as `num`, not as `NO_OF_BITS`.

Comment: While you're mostly right and I didn't DV, it makes *more* sense to use the size of the input as the variable in which the time complexity is expressed, not less.

Comment: @harold: I'm afraid I don't get your point. Are there arguments for using `NO_OF_BITS`?

Comment: Well for one thing it's the standard thing to do, time complexities are almost always expressed in terms of an input size. Expressing it in terms of an input directly is what would be odd.

Comment: @harold: I agree if the input is a string or an array. For an integer input `n`, I'd expect the time complexity to be defined for `n`, not `sizeof(n)`. But you're right : that's the whole point of this question. I suppose everyone agrees on the complexity, they might use distinct `n`s, though.

Comment: If the complexity in question isn't depending on the input then it isn't depending on the input. N usually means the input. If the complexity isn't depending on the input, the complexity isn't depending on N. I'm not sure what the comments here are trying to say. If the complexity in question isn't depending on the input, then it is O(1).

Comment: Well NO_OF_BITS is not an a-priori constant, it's only a compile-time constant (similarly there is a compile-time constant upper limit for array size..). In principle the algorithm works for general bitvectors, and then its runtime scales linearly in the length of those bitvectors.

Comment: Ah, so we're talking about a hypothetical language and runtime where NO_OF_BITS is an variant and unknown value. In this case the question is unclear, because the answer cannot be given. Either way the code in the question bears no mention or sign that NO_OF_BITS is in any way related to the input of the code. If NO_OF_BITS is random then the answer is that it is `O(?)`.

Answer (score 1):

For the reasons you stated, the complexity is not o(n), it is o(1) - that is, constant. Whatever number you plug in, the cost will always be the same and only depend on NUM_OF_BITS.

But if you consider the order by the maximum number N, that is: how does the time vary if you support up to N<sub>1</sub> (say 256), N<sub>2</sub> (say 65536), 1048586 and so on... then you'll see that you need an increasing number of bits, correct? And therefore, the time increases. How much does it increase? Every doubling of the maximum number requires *one* extra bit, which means the time grows like the base 2 logarithm of MaxN. Hence, **perhaps**, the o(log n) you're looking for.